# Excel VBA - Display Recordset in Sheet without looping

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I've got some code which retrieves data from an Access table into `RecordSet`.
I want to display this data on my sheet but I'm struggling to do so.
I've created a sheet called test whilst trying to figure this out and I've tried:

```
Test.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

But that doesn't do anything.
I've been able to populate the sheet with

```
rs.MoveFirst
rowctr = 2
Do Until rs.EOF
    Test.Cells(rowctr, 1) = rs![Name]
    Test.Cells(rowctr, 2) = rs![Account Type]
    Test.Cells(rowctr, 3) = rs![Forecast Date]
    Test.Cells(rowctr, 4) = rs![Forecast Value]
    Test.Cells(rowctr, 5) = rs![Actual Date]
    Test.Cells(rowctr, 6) = rs![Actual Value]
    rowctr = rowctr + 1
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

But I'm assuming there's a better way than this?
I've done this lots with normal arrays and have no issues populating a range with an entire array with a single command.
I've not done too much work with records sets though.

Comment: I usually just use `CopyFromRecordset` (like you show) - it works for me, so maybe there is another problem with another part?

Comment: Was `Test.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs` executed immediately after the  rs was created ?

Comment: yes i used the copyfromrecordset code straight after rs was created

Comment: same place the for loop above is

Comment: How are you creating the recordset ? Did you try `rs.MoveFirst`
 before the `.CopyFromRecordset`

Comment: ah!! brilliant (and also slightly annoying) adding in the rs.MoveFirst fixed it

Comment: Interesting. I did not require that.

Comment: Yeah, this should not be necessary. Please add the full code how you create/open the recordset.